# Cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SELECT ru.roleuser ,
opr.emplid ,
ru.rolename ,
ru.dynamic_sw ,
AU.AUDIT_OPRID ,
TO_CHAR(au.audit_stamp , 'YYYY-MM-DD  HH.MI.SS')
FROM psoprdefn opr ,
psroleuser ru
LEFT OUTER JOIN HRSECADM.wb_audit_psroleuser AU
ON (au.roleuser     = ru.roleuser
AND au.rolename     = ru.rolename )
WHERE opr.oprid     = ru.roleuser
AND (au.audit_stamp =
(SELECT MAX(au_ed.audit_stamp)
FROM HRSECADM.wb_audit_psroleuser au_ed
WHERE ru.roleuser  = au_ed.roleuser
AND au_ed.rolename = ru.rolename
)
OR au.audit_stamp IS NULL) ;
```

**Getting Error :**

```
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table.
```

I faced above issue in above sql.if i want update data on above sql we faces some sql error.
Error Position: 30 Return: 1779 - `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`
Failed SQL stmt:UPDATE PS_ROLUSR_AUD_VW_W SET OPRID=:1 WHERE OPRID=:2 AND EMPLID=:3

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access PeopleSoft DataDictionary tables to do some updates. That is very hot! However, your SQL is a join between two tables. In Oracle it is generally allowed to update a join but there are a few conditions:

- the update affects only one of the base tables
- the other tables must be "key-preserved", that means that each of
  them must have a row in the base table above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the table which is used to join should have some key.

```
DROP TABLE x;

CREATE TABLE x
(
   child    NUMBER (1),                                        -- primary key,
   parent   NUMBER (3),
   notes    VARCHAR2 (10),
   notes1   VARCHAR2 (10),
   notes2   VARCHAR2 (10),
   notes3   VARCHAR2 (10),
   notes4   VARCHAR2 (10)
);

CREATE TABLE y (child NUMBER (1) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (1,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (2,
             1,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (3,
             1,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (4,
             2,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (5,
             1,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (5,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (6,
             5,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (7,
             5,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO x
     VALUES (8,
             6,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             NULL);

INSERT INTO y
     VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO y
     VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO y
     VALUES (5);

INSERT INTO y
     VALUES (6);

SELECT * FROM x;

UPDATE (SELECT x.child,
               x.parent,
               x.notes,
               x.notes1,
               x.notes2,
               x.notes3,
               x.notes4
          FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.parent = y.child
         WHERE     TRIM (notes) IS NULL
               AND TRIM (notes1) IS NULL
               AND TRIM (notes2) IS NULL
               AND TRIM (notes3) IS NULL
               AND TRIM (notes4) IS NULL) z
   SET z.notes1 = 'notes1',
       z.notes2 = 'notes2',
       z.notes3 = 'notes3',
       z.notes4 = 'notes4';
```